# Vuetify - custom color cannot be applied

Tags: vue.js, colors, vuetify.js

- Vuetify version 1.4.0 - basic default setup as I'm new to Vue.js.
  My custom primary color for the v-button is overwritten by standard Vuetify color. Also, I didn't install any additional style files. Here are my files:

=======================================

## App.vue

```
<template>
<v-app>
<v-container fluid>
<v-layout row wrap align-center>
<v-flex class="text-xs-center">
<v-btn color="primary">test</v-btn>      //defaults to factory color
</v-flex>
</v-layout>
</v-container>
</v-app>
</template>


=================================================
main.js
=================================================
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

import Vuetify, {
VApp, // required
VNavigationDrawer,
VFooter,
VToolbar
} from 'vuetify/lib'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
components: {
VApp,
VNavigationDrawer,
VFooter,
VToolbar

},
directives: {
Ripple
}
})

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
theme: {
"primary": "#FB8C00",   
"secondary": "#424242",
"accent": "#FF5252",
"error": "#FF5252",
"info": "#2196F3",
"success": "#4CAF50",
"warning": "#FB8C00"
}
})


Any help is greatly appreciated,
Lesiu
```

Comment: Edit your question so that each file shows corresponding code. I think you incorrectly pasted it.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're calling Vuetify (`Vue.use('vuetify')`). This won't work because Vue.use automatically prevents you from using the same plugin more than once, so calling it multiple times on the same plugin will install the plugin only once.

Instead, remove the remove both `Vue.use('Vuetify', ...)` and replace with **before**  `new Vue({..})`.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import Vuetify, {
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar
} from 'vuetify/lib'

import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    components: {
        VApp,
        VNavigationDrawer,
        VFooter,
        VToolbar
    },
    directives: {
        Ripple
    }, 
    theme: {
        "primary": "#FB8C00",   
        "secondary": "#424242",
        "accent": "#FF5252",
        "error": "#FF5252",
        "info": "#2196F3",
        "success": "#4CAF50",
        "warning": "#FB8C00"
    }
})

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated but it still the same issue:              Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  },
  directives: {
    Ripple
  },
  theme: {
    
  }
})


import Vuetify, {
...
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: You're calling Vue _before_ you're importing it. That's a bit odd, right? That's like eating an apple and afterwards going to the store to buy it (aka impossible). I've updated my answer to show the correct order.

Answer (score -1):

import Vuetify, {
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar
} from 'vuetify/lib'

import Vuetify, {
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar
} from 'vuetify'          // removing /lib   fixed the problem

Vue version: Vue CLI v3.2.1
Vuetfiy version: 1.4.0